# Is it possible to send a notification with different listeningConnectionStrings with one application?

Tags: c#, ios, azure, xamarin

I'm trying to provide info but I can't find any information if it's possible so I guess its not, but I want to make sure and I'm asking the following question to you guys also. Is it possible to send notification from `Azure Notification Hub` with two different `Notification Hub strings` with one application to iOS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm afraid you can't do that. If you want to use two different Notification Hub strings in one application. You have to create two Hubs like below as you have to pass the `ListenConnectionString` as parameter to create a new SBNotificationHub.

```
 Hub = new SBNotificationHub(Constants.ListenConnectionString, Constants.NotificationHubName);
```

I think even if you create two hubs, only one will work.

Refer: [connect-your-app-to-the-notification-hub](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/notification-hubs/xamarin-notification-hubs-ios-push-notification-apns-get-started#connect-your-app-to-the-notification-hub)

And you can see the source code here: [SBNotificationHub](https://github.com/Azure/azure-notificationhubs/blob/master/iOS/WindowsAzureMessaging/WindowsAzureMessaging/SBNotificationHub.m)